# Errors when running Protractor tests - Java Issues?

Tags: javascript, java, protractor

I'm running E2E tests using Protractor/Jasmine. Using VS Code to author.

I had no issue when running these tests/frameworks when running on Win7 but since "upgrading" to Win10, I'm getting errors:

```
PS E:\Projects\DBM_TAGS> protractor dbm-tags.js
[12:01:31] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[12:01:31] I/local - Starting selenium standalone server...
[12:01:31] W/launcher - Ignoring uncaught error Error: spawn C:\Program 
Files\Java\jdk-13.0.2\bin\bin\java ENOENT
[12:02:02] E/launcher - Error: Error: Timed out waiting for the WebDriver server at 
http://192.168.1.241:51064/wd/hub
at onError (C:\Users\david\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\selenium- 
webdriver\http\util.js:102:16)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
[12:02:02] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 100
```

I've never seen the machine's IP shown before...normally it's http://localhost:4444/wd/hub....port 4444 is what's showing when Webdriver-manager starts up.

So apart from the OS nothing has changed...any ideas please?

Further to @yong's comments below...the server IS starting but the error message appears to indicate that protractor **cannot connect** to it.

Here's the Webdriver manager's startup log..

```
PS E:\Projects\DBM_TAGS> webdriver-manager start
webdriver-manager: using local installed version 12.1.7
[14:35:39] I/start - java - 
Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=E:\Projects\DBM_TAGS\node_modules\webdriver- 
manager\selenium\geckodriver-v0.26.0.exe - 
Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=E:\Projects\DBM_TAGS\node_modules\webdriver- 
manager\selenium\chromedriver_80.0.3987.16.exe -jar 
E:\Projects\DBM_TAGS\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\selenium-server- 
standalone-3.141.59.jar -port 4444
[14:35:39] I/start - seleniumProcess.pid: 10956
14:35:42.662 INFO [GridLauncherV3.parse] - Selenium server version: 3.141.59, revision: e82be7d358
14:35:43.030 INFO [GridLauncherV3.lambda$buildLaunchers$3] - Launching a 
standalone Selenium Server on port 4444
2020-02-09 14:35:43.460:INFO::main: Logging initialized @3439ms to 
org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.log.StdErrLog
14:35:44.358 INFO [WebDriverServlet.<init>] - Initialising WebDriverServlet
14:35:45.306 INFO [SeleniumServer.boot] - Selenium Server is up and running on 
port 4444
```

So surely listening is happening on port 4444 and not Port 51064 as per the error. NB: everytime you try to run the tests, a different port number is reported.

Comment: when you run `protractor dbm-tags.js`, from the log it uses webdriver from `C:\Users\david\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\selenium- 
webdriver`.  But when you run `webdriver-manager start`, it uses webdriver from `E:\Projects\DBM_TAGS\node_modules\webdriver- 
manage`.  The former uses global webdriver-manager, the later use local package, check they are same version,maybe it's a direction to fix your issue.

Comment: Thanks!! Yes - that did the trick. Much appreciated @yong

Answer (score -1):

`http://192.168.1.241:51064/wd/hub` is the webdriver start an api server on. If you use chrome, chromedriver.exe will start and expose a url like it.  The api server accept commands from test script, like click, input. Then convert these commands to directives which chromedriver.exe understand how to manipulate browser.

you can run the chromedriver.exe directly from cmd window to see it can start or not.

Comment: Thanks for this but the server IS starting but Protractor cannot connect to the server. Please see my additions to the original comment.